# Call demon thread while spring/server boots up

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, scheduled-tasks

I am using spring 3.1, tomcat 6.0

Whenever the server/Spring boots up, i need to call a demon thread which does some kind of DB clean up. Once it is done the thread will die by itself.

Note: The job should be called only once in the spring lifecycle.

can i use @Scheduled? But it should be called only once?

How to achieve this?

Comment: Please be sure to include at least one language tag for your question. This will help the people that can help you find it. I've tagged it Java, if there is a more appropriate tag please revert and adjust.

Comment: Spring has support for Quartz, there's plenty of documentation on the web

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org). It integrates easily with Spring, and it is used to automate DB tasks at application startup.